# How to set HTTP-headers with Perl?

Tags: perl, http, cgi

I Can't set headers in Perl.

```
print "Expires: Thu, 08 May 2003 08:37:25 GMT\n\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\n\n";
print "Vary: Accept-Encoding\n\n";
```

First one works only. Then I have `Content-Type: text/x-perl`. What is wrong?

Comment: I forget, does HTTP expect double CRLF between headers, or just one?  I know you must include two before the message body.  BTW it's usually `\r\n` for CRLF

Comment: If you use modules that do all that for you, you don't need to know these little details. :)

Comment: Two new lines are used to separate the headers from the body. So your headers end at your first new line (i.e. after your first header).

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you're using CGI to connect your web server to Perl.  CGI uses a blank line to separate the headers from the response body.  Since

```
print "Expires: Thu, 08 May 2003 08:37:25 GMT\n\n";
```

prints a blank line after the `Expires:` header, the remaining print statements are considered part of the body, not headers.  You wanted:

```
print "Expires: Thu, 08 May 2003 08:37:25 GMT\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\n";
print "Vary: Accept-Encoding\n\n";
```

Comment: You might want to remove the second `\n` for the last header line add another line `print "\n"; # finish HTTP header` to avoid this exact mistake when adding more header lines in the future.